# POS development, Multiple invoice option using useState hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to develop a POS using React JS, which intend to have managing three different invoices at a time.
For this purpose I have declared three different variables for each invoice carrying the order details. Each time product is being clicked it triggered "addOrder" function. Based on active invoice number condition it adds the item details in respective invoice details variable, and set "orderlines" using USESTATE hook. To manage the active invoice number I have assigned onClick event to each "Invoice Tab" to update active invoice number.
The problem is, whenever I add product to one invoice and add same product to another invoice and update the quantity it affecting both invoices i.e. updating invoice1_details variable as well as invoice3_details variable.
May someone help me to resolve this problem.

```
let active_invoice = 1;
let invoice1_details = [];
let invoice2_details = [];
let invoice3_details = [];

const [orderlines, setorderlines] = useState(invoice1_details);

    function setInvoice(e, number) {
        active_invoice = number;
        console.log(active_invoice);
        e.target.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".active").forEach(e =>
            e.classList.remove("active"));
        if (active_invoice === 1) {
            e.target.classList.add('active');
            setorderlines(invoice1_details);
            //console.log("In set Invoice1 after setting orderlines");
        }
        else if (active_invoice === 2) {
            e.target.classList.add('active');
            setorderlines(invoice2_details);
            //console.log("In set Invoice2 after setting orderlines")
        }
        else if (active_invoice === 3) {
            e.target.classList.add('active');
            setorderlines(invoice3_details);
            //console.log("In set Invoice3 after setting orderlines")
        }
    }

    function addOrder(ItemDetails) {
        if(active_invoice === 1) {
            const itemIndex = invoice1_details.findIndex((item) => item.ItemNumber === ItemDetails.ItemNumber);
            if(itemIndex === -1) {
                ItemDetails.Qty = 1;
                invoice1_details.unshift(ItemDetails);
                setorderlines([...invoice1_details]);
            }
            else {
                invoice1_details[itemIndex].Qty++;
                setorderlines([...invoice1_details]);
            }
        }
        else if(active_invoice === 2) {
            const itemIndex = invoice2_details.findIndex((item) => item.ItemNumber === ItemDetails.ItemNumber);
            if(itemIndex === -1) {
                ItemDetails.Qty = 1;
                invoice2_details.unshift(ItemDetails);
                setorderlines([...invoice2_details]);
            }
            else {
                invoice2_details[itemIndex].Qty++;
                setorderlines([...invoice2_details]);
            }

        }
        else {
            const itemIndex = invoice3_details.findIndex((item) => item.ItemNumber === ItemDetails.ItemNumber);
            if(itemIndex === -1) {
                ItemDetails.Qty = 1;
                invoice3_details.unshift(ItemDetails);
                setorderlines([...invoice3_details]);
            }
            else {
                invoice3_details[itemIndex].Qty++;
                setorderlines([...invoice3_details]);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a minimal example in Codepen or JSfiddle or something?

Comment: You should consider just making a clone of your `ItemDetails` object after the `if(itemIndex === -1) {` line, `ItemDetails = Object.assign({}, ItemDetails)`

Comment: Clone resolved my problem, Thanks